# Copy data 'Storage Connection' forces to use blob storage in ADF instead of ADLS Gen2

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a data factory with input from ADLS Gen2 (only this is compliant in our company). It works fine.
The pic given below is the settings of 'copy data' activity. As given in the pic for storing logs (missed rows data), we are forced to use blob storage or gen 1 datalake. How can we use ADLS Gen2 for this? Looks like a bottleneck. We will have complacency issues if such data is stored outside Gen2

[image]

Comment: Why you face this? On my side it is no problem.

Comment: Can you show the explanation popup from your side?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lurf1.png This linked service is linked to ADLS gen2 which is named 0730bowmanwindow.

Comment: You seems faced the similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207259/azure-datalake-analytics-u-sql-with-azure-datalake-storage-gen-2 He also can not select but I can.

Comment: What type of linked service did you use?

Comment: You can find it is ADLS gen2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyaaW.png

Comment: just to be sure, in the configuration in portal, 'Hierarchical namespace' is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

On my side it is no problem, please try to directly edit the definition json of your activity:

This is my json:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BinarySource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "BinarySink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "logStorageSettings": {
                        "linkedServiceName": {
                            "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStorage1",
                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                        }
                    },
                    "validateDataConsistency": false
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Binary1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Binary2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me. 1) Please ensure you are using ''Hierarchical namespace' . 2) In the drop down for Storage connection name only Blob storage linked services are visible(Gen2 is ignored), you may provide a screenshot of your adf 3) If I edit the json and point to ADGen2('Hierarchical namespace') and reload ADF then it gives validation error asking me to select the logging LS. Also the logging service is empty (it still is not showing Gen2) 4) Explanation of the field 'storage connection name' clearly excludes Gen2, why?